# Match string to list of defined strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to be able to determine if a string matches a list of defined values.

Say I have a defined list of strings, e.g.

```
a | activ | blue | lagoon | ex (defind list is much longer and contains approx. 50+ possibilties)
```

I should be able to match any of the following;

```
 a
 a[name]
 activ
 activ[class=somevalue]
 blue
 lagoon[name=somevalue], ...e.t.c
```

is it possible via regex to determine if a string passed is contained in the defined list?

thanks...

Comment: Where do `name`, `class` and `somevalue` come from? Do you only want to allow equal signs and square brackets around them?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the string is consistently stored as: `value | value` (with one space between the value and pipe) you could trivially do:

```
str.match(new RegExp(values.split(' | ').join('|'))
```

If you need to math exact words you could use `values.split(' | ').join('\\b|\\b')`

Comment: +1. Or maybe `new RegExp(values.split(' | ').join('|')).test(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(a|activ|blue|lagoon)(?:\[(\w+)=?(\w*)\])?$
```

For "activ[class=something]"

```
group 1 = activ
group 2 = class
group 3 = something
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?:

```
/^(?:a|activ|blue|lagoon)\b(\[(?:name|class)(?:=somevalue)?])?$/.test(yourstring);
```